# How to pass ajax object data to python file

Tags: python, jquery

I have written an ajax code to pass value to python file. I used request.GET['user'] but it gives compile error. Help me to give any method in python to catch the value.
Below is python code:

```
if (request.session.get('word',None) and request.session.get('user',None)):
    print "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('no words submitted')</script>"
else:
    word=request.GET['word']
    user=request.GET['user']
```

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: "http://sudhanshu-gupta-gh.com/wm-mrg/word_to_dictionary_test.py",
    data: {word: word, user: myName},
    success:function(html) { 
    console.log("Word send");
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log("Unable to Load!");
            },
    complete: function(){
        console.log("Word Added")
        }
            });
```

Compile Error:

```
File "word_to_dictionary_user.py", line 8, in <module>
    word=request.GET['word']
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide the code you have so far to make it easier to help you.

Comment: included code but not the error, expect as much effort put into the answers as you put into the question

Comment: Please post your complete `word_to_dictionary_user.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the function does not take `request` as a parameter, but it is impossible to pinpoint the problem since your code snippets are not complete.